# Как получить правильно данные?

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть вот такой запрос:

```
with comments_info as (
    select pc.post_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb("pc") - 'post_id') as comments
    from post_comments pc
             join "user" u on u.user_id = pc.user_id
    group by post_id
) select c.comments from post p
          left join comments_info c on c.post_id = p.id WHERE p.id = 1
```

получаю вот такой результат: `[{id: 1, user_id: 1, description: "description"}]` а нужно получить

```
[{id: 1, user_id: 1, description: "description", username: "username", user_logo: "logo"}]
```

то есть заджойнить так чтобы получить еще и username и user_logo, как это можно сделать?
Модель user:

```
user_id PK
  email varchar
  password varchar
  username varchar
  user_logo varchar
```

Модель post_comments:

```
id PK
  post_id references post(id)
  user_id references user(id)
  description text
```

Comment: @Akina я не знаю что у вас там выводит, но у меня выводит именно так как я написал. _Не стыдно такую ахинею постить?_ А с чего должно быть стыдно стесняюсь спросить? Только начал изучать sql, уверен многие в начале изучения допускают ошибки, пишут как вы выразились _ахинею_, это абсолютно нормально, если вас как профи в sql задевает или раздражает как пишут запросы новички, то для чего вы вообще заходите на вопрос и отвечаете, не лучше ли просто промолчать?

Comment: *для чего вы вообще заходите на вопрос и отвечаете* Сообщаю - в нынешнем варианте вопрос в принципе не предполагает ответа, потому что факты в нём рассогласованы. Ну кроме указания на многочисленные противоречия между сообщёнными фактами. *уверен многие в начале изучения допускают ошибки* Вы разместили этот же вопрос на другом форуме на час раньше. И я почти сразу указал, что вопрос не согласован. Но этот час Вы потратили не на то, чтобы понять или хотя бы спросить, в чём проблема, а на поиск другого форума, на который можно было бы вывалить вот это...

Comment: @Akina _Но этот час Вы потратили не на то, чтобы понять или хотя бы спросить, в чём проблема_ действительно, вопрос был задан также и на другом форуме, где вы также упомянули о том что результат не соответствует запросу, опять же повторюсь что у меня выводит конкретно так как я написал, далее вы предложили выложить create table итд, на что я не ответил, так как я не вижу смысла выкладывать это все именно вам, вчера я также задал вопрос на том же самом форуме, но вы также начали придираться к не рабочему запросу, и называть это _ахинеей_. Именно по этому я не ответил, а этот час я ждал ответа

Comment: *опять же повторюсь что у меня выводит конкретно так как я написал* Из чего следует простой вывод - у Вас приведён вывод ДРУГОГО запроса.

Comment: _у Вас приведён вывод ДРУГОГО запроса._ отличная шутка :) Благодарю вас за дискуссию!

Comment: Смысл выкладывать самодостаточный пример с create table очень большой. Если можно скопировать и запустить ваш пример, то в принципе не возникнет вопросов про то, рабочий ли код. В этом случае ответ получите гораздо быстрее. Мне вот было лень вручную воссоздавать таблицы, так что я не уверен, что ответ синтаксически правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужны две вещи:

1. Функция создания `jsonb` из значений полей - jsonb_build_object
2. Функция слияния двух `jsonb` - `||`

Вот [демо](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)

В результате:

```
with comments_info as (
    select pc.post_id, 
       jsonb_agg((to_jsonb("pc") - 'post_id') || jsonb_build_object('username', u.username, 'user_logo', u.user_logo))
          as comments
    from post_comments pc
             join "user" u on u.user_id = pc.user_id
    group by post_id
) select c.comments from post p
          left join comments_info c on c.post_id = p.id WHERE p.id = 1
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ! В целом это почти то что нужно мне, но получается что приходит вот так: `[{id: 1, user_id: 1, description: description}, {username: username, user_logo: logo}]` то есть username, user_logo идут как другой обьект в массиве, мне бы их соединить в один обьект, чтобы в одном обьекте был id, user_id, description, username, user_logo

Comment: Подправил, возможно заработает. Это все следствие недостаточно хорошо сформулированного вопроса, как я писал в комментарии.

Comment: Благодарю вас еще раз за ответ! Действительно, теперь получаю как нужно! _Это все следствие недостаточно хорошо сформулированного вопроса, как я писал в комментарии._ безусловно, не спорю.